# How to use ternary operator inside map

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a ternary operator inside a map, but not to sure why this is wrong? Getting a parsing error at the end of the ternary

[image]

code:

```
return(

  <div className='Card'>
    <div className='TableTopbar ScheduleGrid'>
      <div>id</div>
      <div>interval</div>
      <div>project_id</div>
      <div>database</div>
      <div>create_timestamp</div>
      <div>create_user_id</div>
      <div>Edit</div>
    </div>

    {scheduleData.map((schedule)=> 

      {UsageMode === 'Read' ? 
      <div className='Table ScheduleGrid'>

        <div>{schedule.id}</div>
        <div>{schedule.interval}</div>
        <div>{schedule.project_id}</div>
        <div>{schedule.database}</div>
        <div>{schedule.create_timestamp}</div>
        <div>{schedule.create_user_id}</div>
        <div>
          <EditIcon
            style={{padding: '2px', width: '0.8em', height: '0.8em', marginRight: '5px'}}
            className='CircleButton'
            onClick={onEditScheduleClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      :
      <div>ID</div>
      }
    )

)



export default scheduleRowTwo
```

Updated code:

```
return(

  <div className='Card'>
    <div className='TableTopbar ScheduleGrid'>
      <div>id</div>
      <div>interval</div>
      <div>project_id</div>
      <div>database</div>
      <div>create_timestamp</div>
      <div>create_user_id</div>
      <div>Edit</div>
    </div>

    {scheduleData.map((schedule)=> 
    (
      {UsageMode === 'Read' ? 
      <div className='Table ScheduleGrid'>

        <div>{schedule.id}</div>
        <div>{schedule.interval}</div>
        <div>{schedule.project_id}</div>
        <div>{schedule.database}</div>
        <div>{schedule.create_timestamp}</div>
        <div>{schedule.create_user_id}</div>
        <div>
          <EditIcon
            style={{padding: '2px', width: '0.8em', height: '0.8em', marginRight: '5px'}}
            className='CircleButton'
            onClick={onEditScheduleClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      :
      <div>ID</div>
      }
    )
)

export default scheduleRowTwo
```

Updated error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, your outermost div does not have a closing tag, thus resulting in an error.

Also, you're missing a return statement.

```
return (
        <div className="Card">
            <div className="TableTopbar ScheduleGrid">
                <div>id</div>
                <div>interval</div>
                <div>project_id</div>
                <div>database</div>
                <div>create_timestamp</div>
                <div>create_user_id</div>
                <div>Edit</div>
            </div>

            {scheduleData.map((schedule) => {
                return UsageMode === "Read" ? (
                    <div className="Table ScheduleGrid">
                        <div>{schedule.id}</div>
                        <div>{schedule.interval}</div>
                        <div>{schedule.project_id}</div>
                        <div>{schedule.database}</div>
                        <div>{schedule.create_timestamp}</div>
                        <div>{schedule.create_user_id}</div>
                        <div>
                            <EditIcon
                                style={{
                                    padding: "2px",
                                    width: "0.8em",
                                    height: "0.8em",
                                    marginRight: "5px",
                                }}
                                className="CircleButton"
                                onClick={onEditScheduleClick}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div>ID</div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
```

Try this code. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose this code block with parentheses because you're trying to implicitly return an object (without the `return` keyword):

```
{UsageMode === 'Read' ? 
      <div className='Table ScheduleGrid'>

        <div>{schedule.id}</div>
        <div>{schedule.interval}</div>
        <div>{schedule.project_id}</div>
        <div>{schedule.database}</div>
        <div>{schedule.create_timestamp}</div>
        <div>{schedule.create_user_id}</div>
        <div>
          <EditIcon
            style={{padding: '2px', width: '0.8em', height: '0.8em', marginRight: '5px'}}
            className='CircleButton'
            onClick={onEditScheduleClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      :
      <div>ID</div>
      }
```

Comment: Hey, the solution didn't seem to work unless I am not adding the parenthesis right? I updated my code in the question

Comment: yes that's right @stackblunter your latest code should work. also, check mymoto's answer. You're missing a closing div tag